# pandas >= 0.18 - setting multi-index name on df from read_csv resulting in TypeError

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multi-index

I've come across an error that has only started occurring after updating pandas to >= 0.18

I have a piece of code that opens a number of csv files and concatenates them into one multi-indexed dataframe. As part of the pd.concat step I set the index names using `names=['Sweep', 'Index']`. Prior to updating from 0.17 to 0.18 this worked fine, but since updating I'm getting the traceback shown below.

I've reduced the issue down to being able to reproduced by this (the example csv can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8vyJMdXzCJYb1BjRjJBTDctSzg/view?usp=sharing)):

```
filename = './example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', 'Index'])
```

This results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\range.py", line 124, in _simple_new
    return RangeIndex(start, stop, step, name=name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\range.py", line 73, in __new__
    start = _ensure_int(start, 'start')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\range.py", line 59, in _ensure_int
    new_value = int(value)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 63, in __repr__
    return str(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 42, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 534, in __unicode__
    line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1486, in to_string
    show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 378, in __init__
    self._chk_truncate()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 450, in _chk_truncate
    frame.iloc[-row_num:, :]))
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 834, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 972, in __init__
    self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1059, in _get_new_axes
    new_axes[self.axis] = self._get_concat_axis()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1111, in _get_concat_axis
    concat_axis = _concat_indexes(indexes)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1129, in _concat_indexes
    return indexes[0].append(indexes[1:])
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py", line 1029, in append
    label = self.get_level_values(i)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py", line 666, in get_level_values
    tz=getattr(unique, 'tz', None))
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\range.py", line 126, in _simple_new
    return Index(start, stop, step, name=name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 214, in __new__
    return Int64Index(data, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\numeric.py", line 107, in __new__
    not issubclass(np.dtype(dtype).type, np.integer)):
TypeError: data type "Index" not understood
```

I've tried this on a couple different machines (thinking maybe it was something anaconda), but I get the issue everywhere.

If I just generate a dummy dataframe and do the same thing, this does not occur. I.e.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(8), "Vals2": range(8)})
pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', 'Index'])
```

works fine.

I can set the name of the index of the dataframe from the imported csv without issue. I.e.:

```
filename = './example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.index.names = ['Index']
```

works fine.

Oddly, if I just run the concat step without the names argument, and then set names in a separate line, this completes fine. However, as soon as I go to use that dataframe, I get the traceback shown above. I.e.:

```
filename = './example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
new_df = pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ])
new_df.index.names = ['Sweep', 'Index']
```

Will run, until I go to view `new_df`. Even more oddly, is I can do things like `new_df.head()`, and that runs fine. But if I just type `new_df` in my terminal to just have it print out, I get the above traceback.

I'm at a loss as to what's going on here, so any help would be appreciated.

** Edit 1**

These are the first 5 rows from the file provided in the link above.

```
data_dict = {' LED': {0: -0.00030517578125,
  1: 0.0,
  2: -0.00030517578125,
  3: -0.00030517578125,
  4: -0.00030517578125,
  5: 0.0},
 ' Primary': {0: -2.74688720703125,
  1: -2.74566650390625,
  2: -2.74627685546875,
  3: -2.74810791015625,
  4: -2.74749755859375,
  5: -2.745361328125},
 ' Secondary': {0: -0.00152587890625,
  1: -0.00457763671875,
  2: -0.0048828125,
  3: -0.00335693359375,
  4: -0.0048828125,
  5: -0.00518798828125},
 'Time(ms)': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.10000000000000001,
  2: 0.20000000000000001,
  3: 0.29999999999999999,
  4: 0.40000000000000002,
  5: 0.5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', 'Index'])
```

This does not produce an error, however.

Comment: what is example.csv?

Comment: It's a csv file generated from my data acquisition software. Basically it's four columns of numeric data with the first row being column headers. I've provided a link to a file that can be used to reproduce this issue (the issue generalizes across different files though)

Comment: right, but without a representative example of that data, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: I don't understand - I'm providing a file that can be used.

Comment: embed a small subset of that data in your code to generate the dataframe. most people aren't too keen on downloading random files from anonymous people on the internet

Comment: It seems a small subset would not trigger the issue actually. The example `df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(8), "Vals2": range(8)})` works fine as poster noted, but `df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(61715), "Vals2": range(61715)})` will produce the error.

Comment: I was just going to comment that the length seems to be the issue. See Edit 1

Comment: Try this: `pd.options.display.max_rows = 10`, then `df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(11), "Vals2": range(11)})` and the concat thing :P. *60* is magic since it's the default value for `max_rows`. The error is in the display code which is trying to split larger dataframes for display, I think.

Comment: ha, interesting. It specifically doesn't like renaming the default index. If you reorder the levels, it still just doesn't like renaming what is now level 0 (was level 1), but renaming the Sweep index is fine

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem.  I'm certain this points to a bug.

#### Evidence

Without downloading your data, just using your simple example that works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(8), "Vals2": range(8)})
pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', 'Index'])
```

Yields something like what you want.  However, if you change the `range(8)` to `range(61)`.  It blows up in a similar fashion.  Yes!, there seems to be something special about the number `61`.  What's more is that if you instead did this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(61), "Vals2": range(61)})
df1 = pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', 'Index'])
```

That works fine... until you try to `print df1`.  The error is coming when it is attempting to display the dataframe.

#### Work around.

I could not get a name in the second spot of the MultiIndex.names attribute and also be able to print/display it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Vals1": range(61), "Vals2": range(61)})
df1= pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', ])
```

#### Demonstration

To prove it works on your data

```
filename = './example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
pd.concat([df, ], keys=['Sweep1', ], names=['Sweep', ])

              Time(ms)   Primary   Secondary       LED
Sweep                                                 
Sweep1 0           0.0 -2.746887   -0.001526 -0.000305
       1           0.1 -2.745667   -0.004578  0.000000
       2           0.2 -2.746277   -0.004883 -0.000305
       3           0.3 -2.748108   -0.003357 -0.000305
       4           0.4 -2.747498   -0.004883 -0.000305
       5           0.5 -2.745361   -0.005188  0.000000
       6           0.6 -2.749634   -0.004578  0.000305
       7           0.7 -2.748413   -0.002441 -0.000305
       8           0.8 -2.746277   -0.004883 -0.000305
       9           0.9 -2.743530   -0.005188  0.000305
       10          1.0 -2.743835   -0.006104  0.000610
       11          1.1 -2.747192   -0.003052 -0.000610
       12          1.2 -2.746277   -0.003052 -0.000305
       13          1.3 -2.742310   -0.009460  0.000000
       14          1.4 -2.747192   -0.007324  0.000305
       15          1.5 -2.746887   -0.004272  0.000305
       16          1.6 -2.740479   -0.001526 -0.000305
       17          1.7 -2.745972   -0.004883 -0.000305
       18          1.8 -2.743530   -0.007629  0.000305
       19          1.9 -2.742310   -0.005188  0.000000
       20          2.0 -2.739258   -0.001526  0.000305
       21          2.1 -2.743835   -0.000610  0.000000
       22          2.2 -2.745056   -0.004883 -0.000305
       23          2.3 -2.742615   -0.006714 -0.000305
       24          2.4 -2.739868   -0.004272  0.000610
       25          2.5 -2.738342   -0.006104  0.000000
       26          2.6 -2.740784   -0.003662 -0.000916
       27          2.7 -2.738647   -0.000610  0.000305
       28          2.8 -2.737732    0.000610  0.000000
       29          2.9 -2.739563   -0.004578  0.000000
...                ...       ...         ...       ...
       99970    9997.0 -2.576599   -0.000305 -0.000610
       99971    9997.1 -2.577515   -0.004578 -0.000305
       99972    9997.2 -2.577209   -0.003967  0.000000
       99973    9997.3 -2.578430   -0.003052  0.000000
       99974    9997.4 -2.580566   -0.004272  0.000305
       99975    9997.5 -2.575684   -0.003357 -0.000305
       99976    9997.6 -2.574463   -0.000916 -0.000305
       99977    9997.7 -2.579651   -0.002747  0.000000
       99978    9997.8 -2.576294   -0.010376 -0.000305
       99979    9997.9 -2.578125   -0.005798 -0.000916
       99980    9998.0 -2.576294   -0.001831  0.000000
       99981    9998.1 -2.577820    0.000000  0.000916
       99982    9998.2 -2.581482   -0.007019  0.000000
       99983    9998.3 -2.575073   -0.005493  0.000000
       99984    9998.4 -2.578125   -0.002136 -0.000305
       99985    9998.5 -2.577515    0.003967 -0.000305
       99986    9998.6 -2.575378   -0.005188  0.000000
       99987    9998.7 -2.577515   -0.007935  0.000610
       99988    9998.8 -2.578430   -0.003967 -0.000305
       99989    9998.9 -2.579346   -0.001221  0.000000
       99990    9999.0 -2.577209    0.001221  0.000000
       99991    9999.1 -2.578125   -0.005798  0.000000
       99992    9999.2 -2.577515   -0.005493  0.000000
       99993    9999.3 -2.573853   -0.002747 -0.000305
       99994    9999.4 -2.575378    0.002441 -0.000305
       99995    9999.5 -2.577820   -0.000305  0.000305
       99996    9999.6 -2.575989   -0.006104  0.000000
       99997    9999.7 -2.576294   -0.007019  0.000305
       99998    9999.8 -2.576599   -0.003662  0.000305
       99999    9999.9 -2.573853   -0.000916 -0.000305

[100000 rows x 4 columns]
```

#### Finally

If you really need that `'Index'` name in there, you can leave it, just don't try to display it.

#### Also Important

[Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) is correct in that people are not keen on downloading random files from the internet.  I took a risk.  However, this bug only manifests if the sample data exceeded 61 records/rows.

Comment: Yes, I had come to find that I could rename the level 0 index, but not the level 1 index and still be able to display it. I assume this is a pandas bug then, and should be opened over on their issue tracker?